# MySQL importing data. Can I import into stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am wondering if I can load data from flat files into multiple tables (requiring multiple inserts) using a stored procedure.

I have a stored procedure already

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Insert_Hockey` (cardyear YEAR, fname VARCHAR(45), lname VARCHAR(45), brand VARCHAR(45), card_id VARCHAR(8))
BEGIN
    /* Create another generic 'Item' in Items table */
    INSERT INTO Items(category_id) VALUES (2);

    /* Need to use the AUTO_INCREMENTED item_id from Items below so use LAST_INSERT_ID */
    INSERT INTO Hockey_Cards VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), cardyear, fname, lname, brand, card_id);
END
```

Now say I have a bunch of data in a spreadsheet about hockey cards. I can export to a tab delimitted format. I want to LOAD DATA FROM FILE but use the tab delimitted data as arguments to the stored procedure. Is something like that possible? If not, how else would you go about importing data in a simple manner in situations like this, where inserts have dependencies on previous inserts.

I am trying to create a few stored procedures / transactions (I don't know if there's a difference in my case) for situations like this in my database. There are a few situations where I use the general table -> specific table type of pattern, where specific table has a foreign key pointing to the general table. So an insert into the specifics requires a prior insert into the general, grab the AUTO_INCREMENTED primary key and use that for an insert into the 'specific' table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can do exactly what you're asking for, but a couple of alternatives that might help:

- Why not use an insert trigger? So you'd have a table for your import data, and an insert trigger on that table. The trigger should get fired for every record, so calling your SP from the trigger should get you what you want.
- The syntax for `INSERT DATA INFILE` allows for some very complex import code. Given a the relatively simple SP code you've shown us, I would expect that you would be able to get `INSERT DATA INFILE` to do this for you itself, without needing an SP. The code will be more complex than the SP, but it certainly should be possible.